# avoid nested if in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to check if `auth.runtime.status`  is equal 200, but something the `auth.runtime` is undifend, is there more elegant way to do it in nodejs

```
    if (auth.runtime) {
            if (auth.runtime.status == 200 && auth.application.status == 200) 



...

 }
}
```

is there a better way to write it?

lets assume I've more nested if

Comment: you need to  add  else condition on your question and then we can help you

Comment: Show as much as possible, i.e. what should happen if `auth.runtime` is `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with a single `if` statement.

```
if (auth.runtime?.status == 200 && auth.application.status == 200)
```

Comment: This assumes `optional chaining operator` is supported by whatever environment the OP is using, and is currently not supported in `Node.js`.